# antd: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am new to react. I was trying to have a `<Button>` from antd design library and I am getting below error.

"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."

Installed react, react-dom, antd via npm. This is reactjs on asp.netcore (used default template from visual studio 2019).

## index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Button } from 'antd';

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
    <div>Success</div>

        <Button type='primary'>PrimaryButton</Button>
        </div>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Hi! I tried that code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-fast-x0vcv) and seems to be working. Maybe you should update with more background or share a repo that throws that error.

Comment: yup seems to be working fine

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It worked when I updated the script verison to the latest dependcies in  package.json. Note for beginners - keep all the dependency files to the latest stable versions.